# Indexable type - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, duck-typing

Below syntax,

```
interface StringArray {
    [index: number]: string;
}
```

states that when a `StringArray` is indexed with a `number`, it will return a `string`. For example -

```
let myArray: StringArray;
myArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];
let myStr: string = myArray[0];
```

So, `myArray` is type constrained on values stored as `string` type, by declaring it with type `StringArray`. Key(index) is always `string` type, under the hood(JavaScript), despite mentioning it as `number`

---

From the below syntax,

```
class Animal{
  name: string;
}

class Dog extends Animal{
  breed: string;
}

interface NotOkay {
  [x: number]: Animal;
  [x: string]: Dog;   
}
```

1. What does `NotOkay` syntax state?

---

From the below syntax,

```
interface NumberDictionary {
    [index: string]: number;
    length: number;    // ok, length is a number
    name: string;      // error, the type of 'name' is not a subtype of the indexer
}
```

2. What does `NumberDictionary` state?

---

3. Why these two syntax are wrong? `error TS2413` & `error: TS2411`

Comment: ?https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: @betadeveloper I have an idea that, javascript converts  indexed object to a string before indexing it. But, I did not get, when that documentation says, *the type returned from a numeric indexer must be a subtype of the type returned from the string indexer*. Firstly, I did not understand the syntax

Comment: The compiler can infer the valid operations based on type of index and the type of  value. In the case of an _NotOkay_  object _o_ that has the number 1 as key and an Animal as its value it would give access to an Animal instead of a Dog when looking up _o_ with the string "1" . The problem is that the property _breed_ is missing in Animals so _o["1"].breed_ will be an invalid operation. If the _number_ index was a subtype of _Dog_, then the operation would be ok because the subtype inherits _breed_ from _Dog_.

Comment: This kind of type check wouldn't totally prevent a runtime error though. It will happily compiles _o["nil"].breed_ even if the "nil" property is undefined in _o_ and it will result in a TypeError when trying to access its breed.

Answer (score 4):

(as @betadeveloper points out, the examples are taken from the typescript documentation at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

1+3) The point the documentation is making is that this declaration is not consistent.

The declaration would seem to say that this code works:

```
let no: NotOkay

function byString(key: string): Dog {
   return no[key]
}

function byNumber(key: number): Animal {
   return no[key]
}
```

But the problem is that a lookup of e.g. `no[0]` is really the same things as `no['0']` (it's how JavaScript works). So `byString('0')` will *actually* just result in an Animal, not necessarily a Dog.

So to prevent the code above – that looks correct but is in fact wrong for certain string keys (those that happen to be numbers in string form) – TypeScript does not allow the declaration.

2+3) `[index: string]: number;` says that you can use any string as an index of a `NumberDictionary` and you will get a number.

On the other hand, `name: string;` says that the property `name` is a string. But a property can also be accessed as an index, so e.g. when doing

```
let nd: NumberDictionary

let a = nd['name']
let b = nd.name
```

a and b mean *exactly the same thing*, but the first declaration seemed to say `a` was a number, whereas the second declaration seems to say `b` is a string. That's a contradiction and therefore this declaration is also not allowed.