# TS2339: Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Y' (Non-indexable type union case)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

### Difference from similar question

In [error TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324949/error-ts2339-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-y), the subject was the [indexable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487415/indexable-type-typescript). Here is not, so most likely the other solutions required.

### Problem

```js
interface INumberPropertySpecification__CommonParameters {
  readonly type: PROPERTIES_TYPES.NUMBER; // enum
  readonly numberType: NUMBER_TYPES; // enum
}

export type NumberPropertySpecification =
      INumberPropertySpecification__Required |
      INumberPropertySpecification__HasDefault |
      INumberPropertySpecification__Optional;
```

In above code, type `NumberPropertySpecification` is the union for below cases:

1. The property is required. In this case, library user MUST comprehend it, so I make him to explicitly specify `required: true`

```js
interface INumberPropertySpecification__Required extends INumberPropertySpecification__CommonParameters {
    readonly required: true;
    readonly invalidValueSubstitution?: number;
}

// Example:

const requiredNumberPropertySpecification: INumberPropertySpecification__Required = {
  type: PROPERTIES_TYPES.NUMBER,
  numberType: NUMBER_TYPES.ANY_REAL_NUMBER,
  required: true // user MUST comprehend it, so I make him to explicitly specify it
}
```

2. The property has default value; it means that it is not required. I don't want to make user to specify `required: false` because it's obviously.

```
interface INumberPropertySpecification__HasDefault extends INumberPropertySpecification__CommonParameters {
    readonly defaultValue: number;
}

// Example
const requiredNumberPropertySpecification: INumberPropertySpecification__HasDefault = {
  type: PROPERTIES_TYPES.NUMBER,
  numberType: NUMBER_TYPES.ANY_REAL_NUMBER,
  default: 1
}
```

3. The property is optional. In this case, user MUST comprehend it, so I make him to explicitly specify `required: false`:

```
interface INumberPropertySpecification__Optional extends INumberPropertySpecification__CommonParameters {
    readonly required: false;
}

// Example:

const requiredNumberPropertySpecification: INumberPropertySpecification__Optional = {
  type: PROPERTIES_TYPES.NUMBER,
  numberType: NUMBER_TYPES.ANY_REAL_NUMBER,
  required: false // user MUST comprehend it, so I make him to explicitly specify it
}
```

### Errors

We can not check `targetPropertySpecification.required === true`. In this case, TypeScript type check algorithm makes overkill, because when `targetPropertySpecification.required` is undefined, no JavaScript error will occur (even if just `if(targetPropertySpecification.required)`, but who uses `"@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions":` can not write such as).

[image]

Same song with `defaultValue` (the `isUndefined`):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very similar to [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), but you're using `required` filed for this.

JavaScript (and TypeScript) distinguish between existing property which has `undefined` value and non-existent property. So to make your code works, you should add optional properties `required` and `defaultValue` to all interfaces.

```
interface INumberPropertySpecification__Required extends INumberPropertySpecification__CommonParameters {
  readonly required: true;
  readonly invalidValueSubstitution?: number;
  readonly defaultValue?: undefined;
}
```

Type of `defaultValue` is explicitly `undefined` and it is set to be optional.

The similar modifications should be done for other two interfaces.

```
interface INumberPropertySpecification__HasDefault extends INumberPropertySpecification__CommonParameters {
  readonly defaultValue: number;
  readonly required?: undefined;
}

interface INumberPropertySpecification__Optional extends INumberPropertySpecification__CommonParameters {
  readonly required: false;
  readonly defaultValue?: undefined;
}
```

Now you can still do

```
const targetPropertySepcification: NumberPropertySpecification = {
  required: true,
  type: PROPERTIES_TYPES.NUMBER,
  numberType: NUMBER_TYPES.T1
}
```

You're not required to provide value for `defaultValue`. It is set to `undefined`.

And following code will work

```
function f1(targetPropertySepcification: NumberPropertySpecification) {
  if (targetPropertySepcification.required === true) {
    // targetPropertySepcification is of type INumberPropertySpecification__Required
    const n: number | undefined = targetPropertySepcification.invalidValueSubstitution;
  } else if (targetPropertySepcification.required === false) {
    // targetPropertySepcification is of type INumberPropertySpecification__Optional
  } else if (targetPropertySepcification.required === undefined) {
    // targetPropertySepcification is of type INumberPropertySpecification__HasDefault
    const n: number = targetPropertySepcification.defaultValue;
  }

  if (targetPropertySepcification.defaultValue === undefined) {
    // Here targetPropertySepcification is of type INumberPropertySpecification__Required | INumberPropertySpecification__Optional 
    //  and required property is of type true | false, or simply boolean
    const rt: boolean = targetPropertySepcification.required
  }
}
```